# Condicional com async em flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async

Eu tenho a seguinte função, que me retorna ou "FREE" ou "PREMIUM". O retorno do banco de dados funciona perfeitamente. Eis o código.

```
userInfoConst() async {
    try {
      var uid = await AuthenticationProvider().getUserId();
      ApiProvider apiProvider = ApiProvider();
      final usuarioModel =
          await apiProvider.getRequest('usuarios/$uid');
      UsuarioModel model = UsuarioModel.fromJson(usuarioModel.data);
      var plano =  model.plano;
      print(plano);
      return plano;
  }
```

O que eu pretendo é fazer a seguinte condicional:

```
if (ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst() == 'FREE') {
      _banner
        ..load()
        ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
    }
```

O problema é que nunca entra no código dentro da condicional, mesmo a condição sendo satisfeita.

Após muito debug e pesquisa eu descobri o seguinte:
 - Não é possível fazer um "condicional assíncrono", ou seja, não tem como usar o async/await junto no **if**.
 - O valor que é retornado da minha função não chega a tempo para fazer a comparação com a string 'FREE', por isso nunca entra.

Já tentei usar o FutureBuilder, mas não deu certo. Já tentei colocar minha função dentro do initState mas também sem sucesso. Todavia acredito que tenha o futureBuilder de forma errada...

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não sei o local que está fazendo essa comparação mas vc já tentou "resolver" o método assíncrono antes de fazer a comparação? `var info = await ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst()` pegaria o resultado, depois que estiver com ele compara `if(info == "FREE") {  ...  }`.

Comment: @LeonardoPaim eu faço a comparação dentro do `widget build`. Não tem como o await diretamente como você citou. Eu teria que usar em um método com o async. Já tentei isso também, mas sem sucesso. Então de certa forma já tentei isso aí que você falou

Comment: Até imaginei que estivesse fazendo dentro do widget mesmo, como vc não deu o código executável pra teste eu citei algo mais superficial possível... teria como disponibilizar um exemplo funcional do seu código? Um que possa ser colado no DartPad mesmo pra facilitar pra todos.

Comment: @LeonardoPaim o código tá no computador da empresa, então não vai dar pra disponibilizar agora...

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando um `FutureBuilder` poderá aguardar até que o método seja processado.

**Exemplo**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: userInfoConst(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Caso não tenha dados renderiza algo
        // um loading por exemplo...
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        // Quando processar será possível utilizar o
        // resultado do Future... Aqui usei apenas um ternário
        // para exemplo...
        return Container(
          color: snapshot.data == "FREE" ? Colors.amber : Colors.red,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Seu método de consulta ao banco de dados...
  userInfoConst() async {
    // Simula um delay de processamento de 2 segundos
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    return "FREE";
  }
}
```

O código pode ser testado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org).

Answer (score 1):

A solução que encontrei fosse essa daqui. Desde já quero agradecer a todos que colocaram aqui sua colaboração.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    buildWidget();
  }

  buildWidget() {
    ApplicationConsts().userInfoConst().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value == "FREE") {
         _banner
        ..load()
        ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
        } 
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```